# How to whitelist IDs in HTML Purifier?

Tags: htmlpurifier

How do you whitelist particular IDs using HTML Purifier?  I know how to blacklist particular IDs:

```
 $config->set('Attr.EnableID', true);
 $config->set('Attr.IDBlacklist' array(
'list', 'of', 'attribute', 'values', 'that', 'are', 'forbidden'
```

));

But I only want to add ONE type of ID, namely "ilo####" (with 1 to arbitrarily many numbers in place of ####).  How do I whitelist only these particular IDs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no direct way to do this. Maybe you can hack around it with %Attr.IDBlacklistRegexp

Comment: Thank you!  I did the following:  `$config->set('Attr.IDBlacklistRegexp','/^(?!ilo)[0-9]+/');`  It looks like it's working.